# How to Add a Verification Code into a Website?(Power Automate Desktop)

Tags: power-automate-desktop

I'm currently automating a login process for a website using Power Automate Desktop (PAD). After submitting my login credentials, the website sends a verification code that I need to input to complete the connection. However, I'm facing challenges in inputting this verification code.

The verification code is a six-digit number, and the website presents it as six individual input fields, each represented as a `<div>`. Alternatively, the website also allows users to input the verification code in a single text field, which is of type `"tel"`.

I've attempted to retrieve the verification code from Outlook and then input it into PAD using separate input actions for each digit, as well as attempting to input it directly into the single Div field. Unfortunately, neither approach seems to work.

Could someone please advise me on the best approach to handle this situation in Power Automate Desktop? Should I be targeting each `<Input>` separately, or should I attempt to input the entire code into the "Div" field?

Thank you for your assistance!

[image]